# Inline assembly --> Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Tags: c, assembly, label, inline-assembly

I have this test file:

```
extern long int VALUE;
extern int *vMEMORY;

void main() {
        (*vMEMORY) = VALUE;
}
```

I want the arm assembly code for it, so I use this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -S -march=armv4 test.c
```

And I get the following file test.s:

```
    .arch armv4
.eabi_attribute 27, 3
.fpu vfpv3-d16
.eabi_attribute 20, 1
.eabi_attribute 21, 1
.eabi_attribute 23, 3
.eabi_attribute 24, 1
.eabi_attribute 25, 1
.eabi_attribute 26, 2
.eabi_attribute 30, 6
.eabi_attribute 34, 0
.eabi_attribute 18, 4
.file   "test.c"
.text
.align  2
.global main
.type   main, %function

main:

@ Function supports interworking.
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
@ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
@ link register save eliminated.
str fp, [sp, #-4]!
add fp, sp, #0
ldr r3, .L2
ldr r3, [r3, #0]
ldr r2, .L2+4
ldr r2, [r2, #0]
str r2, [r3, #0]
add sp, fp, #0
ldmfd   sp!, {fp}
bx  lr

.L3:
.align  2

.L2:
.word   vMEMORY
.word   VALUE
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

I want to change this test.s code into inline assembly code in a C function.
But I don't know how to do it. 
I've tried this:

```
asm volatile (
     "ldr   r3, %0\n"
     "ldr   r3, [r3, #0]\n"
     "ldr   r2, %1\n"
     "ldr   r2, [r2, #0]\n"
     "str   r2, [r3, #0]\n"
     : "=r" (*vMEMORY)
     : "r" (VALUE)
     : "r2", "r3"
);
```

But I get the following error, when I compile the C function:

/tmp/cckOasvT.s: Assembler messages:

/tmp/cckOasvT.s:254: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

/tmp/cckOasvT.s:256: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Could anyone help me to solve the error or tell me how I should change the code?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the lines 254 and 256 correspond to:

```
 "ldr   r3, %0\n"
 ...
 "ldr   r2, %1\n"
```

In both cases, you are trying to load an immediate value into a register (the first time, it's the address of `vMEMORY`, and the second time it's the address of `VALUE`). Both these constants are too large (32 bits) to fit into the immediate field of the instruction (10 bits? I'm not sure). The compiler is trying to work this around by encoding the difference (OFFSET) between the desired address and the program counter, but is still failing, hence the error message.

One solution would be to declare `vMEMORY` and `VALUE` as local variables: that would allow the compiler to place them closer to the function body, reducing the offset.

Another solution would be to do what the compiler did with your original C code - create local variables containing addresses of `vMEMORY` and `VALUE`, and use an extra load instruction to get rid of the indirection later.